# `\section{}`s one column but body two

Tags: floats, sectioning, multicol

I want the sections and tables to be spread across the columns, but the paragraphs and subsections to be two again. I also want figures to be able to stick to the right of the section like this:

```
words words words  words words.

Section title foo bar baz  .-------.
                           | Image |
Words words words  words   '-------'
words words words  words words words
words words words  words words words
```

where the top of the image meets the top of the section heading.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Your try? and MWE?

Answer (score 1):

For figures that are placed differently from what `figure` normally does, use

```
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

and include the figures in the respective environment:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
[\includegraphics, \caption, \label, etc]
\end{wrapfigure}
```

As for tables (and figures) that are called in a twocoulmn text, you write `\begin{table*}` and `\end{table*}` to make them spread across a twocolumn document.

To have both, onecolumn and twocolumn, you can use `\usepackage{multicol}` in a onecolumn document to get parts of the document with two column like this:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some two column text
\end{multicols}
```

but I guess mixing up one and two columns in a document could end up messy...

Edit: inserting graphics might be more complicated than this. You will probably have to move them around within the text to get them in the right column and it would require a more sophisticated solution to get graphics in an area where they overlap with onecolumn and twocolumn text simultaneously (if even possible)...